# Is there a name for this broken glass effect?

Tags: photoshop

[image]

Also, if there are any tutorials and/or help that would be useful.

Comment: "crappy broken mirror effect"?

Comment: Thought of it before asking and nope , just found some "does a broken mirror really bring unluck ? :O :O "

Comment: The point is you probably need to include that description in your question. Please see   http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions

Comment: Edited it , best i could do

Comment: Hum... Broken glass effect?

Comment: I found [this](http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-how-to-create-a-broken-mirror-effect-with-clipping-maskacws-in-illustrator--vector-6478) It might give you an idea; although it is for illustrator..

Answer (score 3):

This is called **[Dispersion Effect](https://www.google.com/search?q=photoshop%20dispersion%20effect&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)** and is most commonly done using Splatter effects. There are thousands of tutorials on how to achieve it.

The basic method is to duplicate your subject layer, transform / move it in some way, apply a Layer Mask, invert that layer mask so none of the new subject is showing, then use stylized brushes to "paint" the subject back in.

Answer (score 0):

You could duplicate your image and slice that new layer into pieces (e. g. using masks) and move them around.
On top of that you could add an image of broken glass (try out the blending modes, until you find a pleasing one).

That's how your example image seems to have been done.